# A nil value, tried everything

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have problem with nil variable. It happens to me often, as I'm beginner with lua. Here's the error message I get:

```
attempt to index global 'popUp_circle' (a nil value) stack traceback
```

And code I'm using:

```
function popUp(header, text)
    local popUp_overlay = display.newImageRect("images/transparent_black.png", 480, 320)
        popUp_overlay.x = halfW
        popUp_overlay.y = halfH
        popUp_overlay.alpha = 0.3
        group:insert(popUp_overlay)

    local popUp_background = display.newImageRect("images/popUp.png", 300, 150)
        popUp_background.x = halfW
        popUp_background.y = halfH
        group:insert(popUp_background)

    local popUp_header = display.newText(header,0,0,native.systemFont,14)
        popUp_header.x = halfW+5
        popUp_header.y = halfH-47
        group:insert(popUp_header)

    local popUp_text = display.newText(text,0,0,native.systemFont,14)
        popUp_text.x = halfW
        popUp_text.y = halfH+10
        group:insert(popUp_text)

    local popUp_circle = display.newCircle( halfW+135, halfH-55, 8 )
        popUp_circle:setFillColor( 0 )
        popUp_circle.alpha = 0.3
        group:insert(popUp_circle)
        timer.performWithDelay( 100, timerCircle )
end

function onClickCircle()

end

function timerCircle()
    popUp_circle:addEventListener( "tap", onClickCircle )
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`popUp_circle` is defined as a local in `popUp` and so is not seen in `timerCircle`.

Comment: Oh, so if i make a local variable inside of a function, i cannot use it later out of the function? And i thank you very much for helping me solve this problem. It helped me a lot, im just a newbie. :)

Comment: @Bartando, yes, that's what *local* means.

Comment: and how do i call _global_ variable?

Comment: @Bartando You don't. All variables are global (really *environmental*, if you are familiar with Lua environments), unless defined as `local` in current scope or that scope's outer scope and so on. You have two options here: 1. remove `local`, so `popUp_circle` will be global; 2. put `local popUp_circle` at top of your module, so `popUp_circle` will be module/file-wide local without polluting global namespace.

Comment: @Bartando Ah, Scholii already explained that. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use `popUp_circle` in another function, that function must have access to now. As it is, it is local to your `popUp` function. Return `popUp_circle` from that function and pass it to `timerCircle`:

```
function popUp(header, text)
    ...
    return popUp_circle
end

puc = popUp(header, text)
timerCircle(puc)
```

Alternately, make it a local to your module:

```
local popUp_circle 

function popUp(header, text)
    ...
    popUp_circle = display.newCircle(...
    ... 
end
```

In that case there is no need to return it or pass it to `timerCircle`, which is tempting (less code), but once your module gets large because you added tons of logic to it ;) lots of module globals will make debugging more complicated. That said, if you subdivide your module into multiple modules required by your `main.lua`, then each file becomes an object of sorts, and these module globals can be treated as data members of the object.

If you don't declare `popUp_circle` local at the module level, it will be a true global, "polluting" the global namespace, definitely to be avoided.

Comment: Thank you too, this helped me a lot. You made it clear for me :)